# Any way to forward drag/drop events to embedded process window?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, webview, pyqt

**A bit of background:**

I need to embed a webview of some kind into a Qt application (that embeds python/PyQt) in order to display some html content. I am stuck with the MinGW build of Qt because that is what the Windows version of our software is built with and it is not feasible to migrate over to Visual C++. Unfortunately for me, `QtWebKit` has been removed from recent versions of Qt and its replacement, `QtWebEngine`, is not supported by the MinGW builds of Qt.

It appears my remaining options are one of

- Maintain a custom build of Qt that reincludes the old QtWebKit code.
- Embed some other rendering engine.
- Launch a web browser in a separate process and embed its window in the main program.

---

I have looked into the first two options, and both sound like a bit of a PITA with a combination of outdated/abandoned code, and complicated build processes with patchy/outdated/conflicting documentation, and limited Windows support.

I've decided to explore the option of embedding a web browser process into my application. I've been successful at getting a firefox process embedded in PyQt using `QWindow::fromWinId` and `QWidget::createWindowContainer`

```py
self.process = QtCore.QProcess()
self.process.setProgram('C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe')
self.process.start()

time.sleep(1)
hwnd = get_window_handle(self.process.processId())

ext_win = QtGui.QWindow.fromWinId(hwnd)
widget = QtWidgets.QWidget.createWindowContainer(ext_win)
widget.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.ForeignWindow)
self.layout().addWidget(widget)
```

I can drag and drop html files into the embedded firefox window and they load just fine. I thought I might be able to exploit this feature by faking drag/drop events in order to programatically load files.

```
def fakeDragDropEvent(self, urls):
    point = QtCore.QPoint(self.width()/2, self.height()/2)

    self.mimedata = QtCore.QMimeData()
    self.mimedata.setUrls(urls)

    dragevent = QtGui.QDragEnterEvent(point, QtCore.Qt.CopyAction, self.mimedata, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier)
    app.postEvent(self, dragevent)

    time.sleep(0.1)

    dropevent = QtGui.QDragEnterEvent(point, QtCore.Qt.CopyAction, self.mimedata, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier)
    app.postEvent(self, dropevent)
```

These fake events can be picked up by the main window etc when I implement event handlers and set `acceptDrops(True)`, however they seem to have no effect on the embedded process window.

**Is there any way to make my embedded process window pick up these events? Or do I maybe need to program the drag/drop events using the native Windows API instead?**

I'm also open to any other suggestions about how I can display html in my application.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don’t have a full solution. I would suggest you check how firefox opens new tabs in an existing process itself and see if you can exploit that somehow.

Comment: The option you opted for won't work. It **will** deadlock at some point, since neither application is prepared to maintain a cross-thread window hierarchy. Long story: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)

Comment: Also: [Replaying input is not the same as reprocessing it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121206-00/?p=5903).

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for the links, those are things hadn't considered. Sounds like embedding a process is out of the question then.

Comment: The standard Windows-only solution to displaying HTML is to use a [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040.aspx) ActiveX control. I believe this uses some older IE release' rendering engine. Make sure to verify, whether all features you need are supported.

Comment: @IInspectable I forgot to mention that I tried the ActiveX control also. It seems to be too outdated and slow. Most of my content wouldn't render properly.

Comment: ActiveX is *still* a thing? Man, the 90ies never go away…

Comment: @JonasWielicki: You say that as though you believe a technology necessarily needs to be new, to be any good. The opposite is usually true. ActiveX and COM are still the **only** technologies that have fully solved the most pressing issues in interoperability. You probably haven't even understood, which problems COM (and ActiveX as an implementation) solve. The 90ies may be gone, but we still have to solve the very same problems.

Comment: @IInspectable I didn’t mean to disregard. In fact I quite like the 90ies, and I have to admit that I have not much idea about the *modern* windows platform in general. I did a few things back in the days with COM and ActiveX, but nothing recent. Didn’t know that it was still a thing ☺.